# why the layout differs in the print view from the web view?

Tags: asp.net, reporting, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Q:

I make a report . the problem is:

The web view (aspx) differs from the the print view.

In aspx (I have 4 pages ),I control this through setting `PageBreakAtStart` and `PageBreakAtEnd`.And the alignment is right as i want.

In print view(I have 6 pages ,Two more empty pages!!and the bottom margin is large in the last four pages).the alignment of some elements is left!!

How to make the print view the same as what i see in the web view?

Comment: need to be in the settings preset paper size and margins, and of A4 or letter format,

Comment: I am afraid that because of conditional visibility and SSRS limitations, you cannot match perfectly the html & print layout. I ll tell you if I find something

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS 2008 printing single page renders different for print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238566/ssrs-2008-printing-single-page-renders-different-for-print)