# SSRS limit data size to page size

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In SSRS report, the HTML rendering is displaying around 20 records. Now when i generate the PDF, only 5 records are displayed per page. I want that both the HTML renderer and PDF renderer should be same. Is there any workaround for the same?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and help us reproduce the issue, and share your research and the solutions you've tried so far?

Comment: When we are trying to render the report in report viewer we get 10 pages whereas when the report is rendered in PDF it generates 20 pages, we want same number of pages at both places ,here we have grouping on the basis of one of columns and we cannot use row ceiling as it repeats the header on every page

Comment: I got that much from your current question. But put yourself in our shoes: how can we help you without resorting to guessing at solutions? We need a way to [reproduce](http://sscce.org) the problem to be able to reliably help you. In addition, it's considered good form to show [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) yourself to solve the problem, and why your solutions didn't work.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238566/ssrs-2008-printing-single-page-renders-different-for-print/2249353#2249353) but my answer wasn't upvoted or accepted so I can't close it as duplicate - reproducing my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The different renderers are rendering the report appropriately for their output. The web viewer is optimised for screen-based reading and generally allows more content per page than the print renderer does as the print renderer is constrained by the paper size that it formats to. Thus you get more pages when rendering for printing than web; however, the content of the report is exactly the same.

The best illustration of this is the Excel renderer - the Excel renderer renders the entire report onto a single worksheet in most cases (for reports with grouping and page breaks set on the group footer it will render each group on its own worksheet). You wouldn't want the Excel renderer to artificially create worksheets to try to paginate your report. It does the appropriate thing which is to include all the data in one big worksheet even though that may be logically thought of as one big "page".

The web renderer page length is determined by the InteractiveHeight attribute of the report (in the InteractiveSize property in the Properties pane for the report) but the interactive height is an approximation rather than a fixed page break setting and your page breaks may still not conform to the print version even though the InteractiveHeight is set to the same length as your target page length.

See [this discussion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677573.aspx) of rendering behaviour for more information on why what you are trying to achieve isn't achievable.