# SSRS reports - Pages different in PDF, word formats

Tags: reporting-services, pagination, ssrs-2008-r2, page-break

I have a SSRS report that has 11 pages in the report, when it is exported into a PDF format number of pages increase to 34 with no additional blank pages in it. Report is exported to PDF with out any data loss and with out any additional blank pages, my problem is if a page is numbered 2 in report, in PDF the contents of page 2 do not match with page 2 in SSRS report. any pointers on how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS 2008 printing single page renders different for print](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238566/ssrs-2008-printing-single-page-renders-different-for-print)

Comment: Hello Chris, can you explain if it is possible to achieve this in ssrs reports?

Comment: No, this is by design. It gives the best functionality of the renderers at the sacrifice of the page numbering being different in each renderer. It is what we call a "training issue". In other words, you can't fix it so you have to educate your users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also doing reports and have many similar issues related to this. And on my experience this are the cause of my problems:

- **Table width or height or both is greater than the page size.**

[image]

In the image you can see that the Page **Width: 8.5 in** and **Height: 11 in** but my total page Margin of Left: 1 in and Right: 1 in is **2 in** and total margin Top: 1 in and Button: 1 in is **2 in**. So my only reusable **Width = 6.5 in** and **Height = 9 in**.

Formula: 
`Reusable Width = Width - (Margin Left + Margin Right)`
`Reusable Height = Height - (Margin Top + Margin Bottom)`

Solution: Adjust your report width or your margins so its within your reusable width and height.

- **Printer Set-up issue**

I remember doing a report for our client. I tested printing it before deploying to our client and its just two page during my print test. But when our client tested the print they got 3 pages which puzzled me since I thoroughly tested it considering its page width and height.

Then upon seeing their print-out their text is bigger and looks zoom-in. I then asked for their printer set-up and compare to ours and it seems they have done some adjustment to their printer that's why we have different output.

Solution: `Adjust the printer set-up`

- **Click Print Layout before exporting to pdf.**

Just normal clicking Preview won't tell you the exact number of page when you export it.
[image]

In the image you can see the **?** on page 2 and it doesn't tell you the exact total page. Now see the other image below after I clicked the Print Layout the total page I will be expecting is showed.
[image]
Solution: `Click the Print Layout before exporting.`